# Wireless: (if harmful) is a bigger WiFi antenna a bigger health hazard?

Tags: wireless-networking

> This question has been reworded to not assume that radio waves are
>   harmful to human beings.

The official message claims there is no real danger to human health in wireless radiations, like the WiFi ones.

But, as long as such official message has been the same for decades concerning to things like *tobacco* or even *radioactivity*, many people have fears about the possibility.

Such people would prefer, when possible, to deploy wireless systems that will potentially emit a lesser perturbation to their bodies.

So, for those that have decided (I am one of them) to believe that:

- A radio wave is potentially harmful.
- WiFi devices emit radio waves.
- A WiFi device with more power (say a [2000mW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0038Q4AIG) wireless device instead of a [200mW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BFPS6S) one) could potentially damage more the health of persons who are nearby.

Can we say the same about antennas? Is a higher gain antenna (more dB/dBi/dBm) more (potentially) troublesome for the health of people?

As long as there are probably many computing-related persons that think the Prudence Directive must be kept for new technologies, answers to this question could be worthful for a computer technical.

> Further info (due to **documentation requests** from the forum) that
>   points to **relationship** between radio waves and human **diseases**
>   (hard to find googling as for today, on July 2015... why could it
>   be?):
>
> 1. Leif G. Salford et al., “Nerve Cell Damage in Mammalian Brain After Exposure to Microwaves from GSM Mobile Phones,” Environmental Health
>      Perspectives 111, no. 7 (2003): 881-883.
> 2. Allan H. Frey, Sondra R. Feld and Barbara Frey, “Neural Function and Behavior,” Annals of the New York Academy of Sciences 247 (1975):
>      433-439.
> 3. Allan H. Frey, “Evolution and Results of Biological Research with Low-Intensity Nonionizing Radiation,” in Modern Bioelectricity , ed.
>      Andrew A. Marino (New York: Dekker, 1988), 785-837, at 809-810.
> 4. California EMF Program, The Risk Evaluation: An Evaluation of the Possible Risks From Electric and Magnetic Fields (EMFs) From Power
>      Lines, Internal Wiring, Electrical Occupations and Appliances (2002),
>      app. 3.
> 5. Örjan Hallberg and Olle Johansson, “1997 - A Curious Year in Sweden,” European Journal of Cancer Prevention 13, no. 6 (2004):
>      535-538.
> 6. Örjan Hallberg and Olle Johansson, “Does GSM 1800 MHz Affect the Public Health in Sweden?” in Proceedings of the 3rd International
>      Workshop Biological Effects of EMFs,” Kos, Greece, October 4-8, 2004,
>      361-364.
> 7. Örjan Hallberg and Olle Johansson, “Cancer Trends During the 20th Century,” Journal of Australian College of Nutritional and
>      Environmental Medicine 21, no. 1 (2002): 3-8.
> 8. David E. Janes Jr., “Radiofrequency Environments in the United States,” in 15th IEEE Conference on Communication, Boston, MA, June
>      10-14, 1979, vol. 2, 31.4.1-31.4.5.
> 9. (Spanish): "[Salud y Antenas Móviles - El experimento biológico más grande de la historia](http://www.rebelion.org/noticia.php?id=54504)" - Rebelion.Org
> 10. (Portuguese): Censored article "[Saude e Antena Telemovel](http://www.laleva.cc/portugal/antenas/saude.html)" at Planetary Association for Clean Energy, Volume 10, number 1, pages 5-6
>       .

Comment: http://www.quora.com/Are-WiFi-signals-harmful-to-the-human-body sicence havent prove yet that wifi signal is harmful for body

Comment: The words "it is clear" are not a magic wand that lets you state controversial things without providing evidence. Water can kill you, does that mean it's never innocuous? Does that mean more of it is always worse than less?

Comment: Every one of your "it is clear" points actually have not been proven

Comment: a different length of antenna would not change the ammount of power , only the tuning, the direction and concentration to areas of waves , the interaction with the ground plane etc, so determining how that would change any possible effects it has would be to first determine where the person is, and where the waves head , and bounce and run into and disperce  on and on endlessly.  If you want to study a specific situation in a partially factual way it would require metering at the location the person would be existing, or all the places the person could exist..

Comment: @Psycogeek , I did read somewhere that human skull is not designed to block radio waves (the brain is not designed to face radio, neither), as long as they are mostly blocked by the ionosphere and they did never exist on the surface until now. So, maybe some studies about radio waves metering as a function of the antenna length/gain/sensitivity could be enough to answer the question. Probably such results would change depending on the bouncing you mention (on walls, floors... etc).

Comment: To meter in one location for one specific layout would not indicate anything for everyone, the variations for different devices, locations, placement and all could change the quantity 100+ fold.  Some generalisations might be able to be made from it based on specifics for for a particular tested setup, but it would be irresponcible to claim that represented a reality for everyone.

Comment: The extent to which radio waves affect human health and the potential impact of antenna design are, unfortunately, not a question about computer hardware or software.  This is the wrong site to be asking this question.

Comment: @fixer1234 , you are right. But, in practical terms, it is one of the question I use to hear on computer shops. Furthermore, I work as I.T. scientist, and it is one of the things some (not all) customers ask about. Maybe some practical knowledge about this matter could be worht for hardware & software engineers.

Comment: long discussion here - https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/wi-fi-are-there-any-health-risks-158657/

Answer (score 3):

If we don't have to back up our claims with evidence, we can say whatever we want. So sure, we can say: "It is clear that bigger antennas are more dangerous."

Answer (score 1):

**"Can we say the same about antennas?"** - NO, it is just a piece of metal, it does not radiate on its own.

**"Is a better (more gain) antenna (more dB/dBi/dBm) more (potentially) troubleous for the health of people?"** - It depend where you stay. If you are behind of focal focus - then there practically no any radiation at all, but if one stay in direction of focal focus - then he/she will get more radiation than a simple omni (piece of stick) antenna that radiate almost in all direction.

BTW, Do you use a cell phone ? It radiate much much more than Wi-Fi, especially when you far from cell tower. Try also to barrow oscilloscope and touch central lead - you will see that electrical field all around your home, because all your home is powered and since it is AC with 60 Hz it radiate much more than Wi-Fi, especially closer to wires with big loading.

Ahh, almost forget, if you aren't in a rural area, - do you know that power meter outside of your home has embedded cell phone unit that makes "smart power grid", it radiates too much more than Wi-Fi...

IMHO, you can't escape from "civilization" especially just eliminating a Wi-Fi only.